# App permissions on Android Marshmallow in PhoneGap

Tags: android, file, cordova, permissions, location

In Android Marshmallow we need to give access to Location, File etc separately in Apps.
Is there any wan in PhoneGap app that I can check is permissions are available or not and prompt the user to provide the permissions.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE 16/02/2016**

Phonegap Build now [supports API 23](http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/02/09/phonegap_6_now_on_build/) - hoooray!

Or if you build locally, just Cordova/Phonegap CLI 6+ and you'll get cordova-android@5+ platform by default.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Currently, this is certainly possible using the Cordova/Phonegap CLI, but [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) doesn't yet support API 23 (Android 6.0 / Marshmallow).

Firstly, you need to use v5.0.0 (or above) of the Android platform, which uses API 23.

As of today, the default version is 4.1.1 (which uses API 22), so you need to explicitly specify the version when adding platform:

```
cordova platform add android@5.0.0
phonegap platform add android@5.0.0
```

The core plugins themselves are in the process of being upgraded to support requesting of appropriate Android 6 runtime permissions. So you'll need to install the "bleeding edge" versions directly from the master branch of the GitHub repos, as opposed to via the npm plugin registry. For example, use:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file
```

which should get you version 4.0.1-dev.

Not the npm release version:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

which will get you v3.0.0

Note that the versions on the master branches are not releases, so may contain bugs.

So the alternative (which I have opted for), is to continue using the release versions of the plugins (which don't yet support requesting of Android runtime permissions), but use [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) to request the Android runtime permissions that the corresponding core plugin requires before attempting to use the core plugin API.

For example, to use the Location plugin, continue to use the release version via npm:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation
```

But before requesting a location, ensure that runtime permission has been granted using the diagnostic plugin:

```
function requestLocation(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
}

cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getLocationAuthorizationStatus(function(status){
    if(status == "GRANTED"){
        requestLocation();
    }else{
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestLocationAuthorization(function(status){
                if(status == "GRANTED"){
                    requestLocation();  
                }else{
                    // Handle other cases
                }
            }, function(error){
                console.error(error);
        });
    }
}, onError);
```

Comment: you are mostly right, but instead of adding the plugin from github, that as you said, it will install the -dev version, he should install the latest version released using ```cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file@4.0.0 --save```

Comment: the approach above always returns me "GRANTED". However, I am still not allowed to get location data. When I check app permissions, it still does not get location permission.

Comment: @VipulAggarwal See this [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin-example) for a working example of how to implement this

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to explicitly ask the user to enable a specific permission with following Cordova plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-permissions

Especially for older plugins this can be very useful.