# Set app permissions on Android 6.x (Marschmallow) in phonegap/cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Beginning with Android 6.x (Marshmallow), the app should doesn't ask for permission before installing but while running.

I'm developing an app with phonegap that uses a barcode plugin in. When I run this app on Android 6.x it neither asks the user for permission before installing nor during run time. Instead it just shows you a box that the app is not working and the device has to be restarted.

According to http://phonegap.com/blog/2016/02/09/phonegap_6_now_on_build/ I added the following line into my config.xml file of my project (path: myProject/config.xml):

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.0.0" />
```

I deployed locally, but it would still show the same error. Is there a way how to fix it? I'd prefer the app is showing this box before starting the installation.

***UPDATE***: In my manifest.xml I set it to his:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

I now have reduced the `targetSdkVersion` from 23 to 22. And the error doesn't show up. But it also doesn't ask for permission. How can I let it ask for permission?

Comment: May be you can try with `<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>`.

Comment: Why? Is this a hack? Looks like a workaround?

Comment: Have you get it worked ?

Comment: Check this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117301/app-permissions-on-android-marshmallow-in-phonegap

Comment: I know this question already. It basically links to the page I posted at the very beginning. See also my update in the OP at the bottom.

Comment: Check this also http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/configuring_features.md.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Android 6 you need to request permission to use the camera at runtime when targeting API level 23+. Even if the uses-permission tag for the Camera is present in AndroidManifest.xml

Try link given below for Checking permission..

[barcode-link](https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/BarcodeScanner)

Example usage:

```
function hasCameraPermission() {
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.hasCameraPermission(
      function(result) {
        // if this is 'false' you probably want to call 'requestCameraPermission' now
        alert(result);
      }
    )
  }

  function requestCameraPermission() {
    // no callbacks required as this opens a popup which returns async
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.requestCameraPermission();
  }
```

good luck..

Comment: Is there any additional plugin we need to install to make this work. Coz its not working for me.