# alt beacon cordova not detecting beacons

Tags: android, cordova, altbeacon

I have a native Android SDK that uses the latest AltBeacon library.
I use my SDK within several Apps to detect beacons and perform business logic.

I now need to include my SDK within a Android Cordova app but it does not detect any beacons. (It does work within an iOS Cordova app). This is probably due to the Bluetooth management being controlled by Cordova and hence not allowing the Altbeacon lib to do it's thing.

Should the Altbeacon lib work within the Android Cordova environment and if so can someone point me in the right direction to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the main issues are:

1. You need to set up the Android  AppManifest.xml to enable Bluetooth LE permissions, and declare the scanning service.  The native library AAR file gets this into your native app's manifest via manifest merging.  You probably need to copy the entries manually from [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml).
2. On Android 5+ you need to request location permissions at runtime to scan for BLE beacons, otherwise you will get no results.  I have not configured a Cordova app to request location permissions on Android, but you may get some hints from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117301/app-permissions-on-android-marshmallow-in-phonegap).

If you do both these things and still have trouble, I would capture a LogCat excerpt and look for anything bluetooth related coming frin your app, and post the results in your question.

Comment: Yes these are all present. I will look into the LogCat again as I recall that no bluetooth information was being sent, unlike within a native app where alt-beacon reports all beacons it sees.

Comment: I will mark this as answered as the information you provided help me to the work out the solution. Thanks.

Comment: What ended up being the solution for you?